# Are Goosebumps books all in the same universe?

Tags: goosebumps

I've always assumed that all Goosebumps books take place in the same universe.

Is there any evidence in the books to support (or disprove) this assumption?

Comment: I've [asked him on Twitter](https://twitter.com/tombquestwiki/status/924999245979181060).

Comment: @Mithrandr update ASAP if he replies! Regardless I still want in-book evidence.

Comment: Related: https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/78/58

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably is, because in the *HorrorLand* series, characters like the Morrises, Carly Beth Caldwell, and the Deeps all come together. Also, in *Return To HorrorLand*, Evan appears on a talk show to talk about his adventures in the *Monster Blood* books and Amaz-O from *Bad Hare Day* also appears.

Comment: This is a great answer! However, if you could, can you add the talk show video? It will certainly increase the credibility of this answer.